# Вы бы поставили обозначенную в последующем предложении запятую или обошлись бы без неё?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, и

В тот раз меня совсем уж сильно переклинило(,) и ты просто попалась под мою горячую руку.

Comment: А в чём видится сложность, ведь ответ очевиден?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы поставила запятую:

***В тот раз меня совсем уж сильно переклинило, и ты просто попалась под мою горячую руку.***

Это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), при наличии **общего обстоятельства** «в тот раз» запятая не ставится, если обстоятельство относится к обоим простым предложениям в составе ССП.

Но в данном случае частица «просто»  **препятствует объединению** предложений, между ними прослеживается причинно-следственная связь (*попалась случайно*).

Для сравнения: *В тот раз меня просто «переклинило»  и ты попалась под горячую руку.*

Чтобы не ставить запятую, желательно также максимально упростить предложения – в этом случае их можно прочитать «слитно», в одну фонетическую фразу.

Comment: Простите, поправил бы последнюю фразу, но не соображу как: полная несочетаемость.

Comment: Спасибо, извините... Сейчас сама поправлю.